# Chart.js doughnut chart comes bigger and bigger

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

I'm new using chart.js and i'm trying to create a very simple doughnut chart.
it's working & the chart is display, but it growths indefinitly in my page.

**HTML Code :**

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 container container-activ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 container-title">
            <span>Actif</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 container-info">
            <span>4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 container container-prevBudget">
        <div class="col-xs-12 container-title">
            <span>Budget prévisionnel</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 container-info">
            <span>180K €</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 container container-allocBudget">
        <div class="col-xs-12 container-title">
            <span>Budget Alloué</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 container-info">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="45" height="45"></canvas>

            <span>32%</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 container container-archived">
        <div class="col-xs-12 container-title">
            <span>Archivé</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 container-info">
            <span>4</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS Code :**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.Cll = {};

        // Initialize Page Beadcrumb.
        jQuery.Cll.breadCrumb = new BreadCrumb([{ "@Resources.Index.BreadCrumbSegment1": "" }]);
        CLLHeader.onLoaded = function () {
            jQuery.Cll.breadCrumb.render();
        };

        $("#cllLeftMenu").cllLeftMenu({
            url:  @Html.Raw('"' + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Url) ? "" : Model.Url) + '"'),
            identifier:  @Html.Raw('"' + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Identifier) ? "" : Model.Identifier) + '"'),
            loadingTrsl: '@Shared.CurrentlyLoadingMsg'
        });

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: ["1", "2"],
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: [
                      "#2ecc71",
                      "#3498db",
                    ],
                    data: [12, 88]
                }]
            }
        });
    });
```

**Edit**: I add more code from HTML & JS And for info i'm using bootstrap

**Edit 2** : I reproduced my issue in this [JsFidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztus6jv3/)

Comment: This code is not causing the issue https://plnkr.co/edit/NAr90Dso0fHY6ZzdLOVR?p=preview . there must be something else. could you share more code ?

Comment: Why is so big, it should be 45*45 no?

Comment: it does not take the width just try with  <canvas id="myChart" height="45" ></canvas>, check the plunker, i have updated the same

Comment: Works on the plunker but not in my page :(

Comment: could you try to replicate it on a fiddle/plunker. BTW are you using razor engine ?

Comment: Yes this is an asp.net application and I am using razor into my pages

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem comes from the css, the chart was in a display : table-cell.

Thanks to **@Deep**